# При зуме изображения фигуры по клику мыши ставятся в неправильном месте

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside2

Привожу в пример небольшое приложение. В нем выводится изображение, на котором нужно отрисовывать фигуры. Если не приближать изображение, то все норм.
Но при увеличении изображения фигура ставится не там где надо.

В данном примере по клику на изображении ставится точка. Если не менять зум, то всё ок. А если приближать, то точка ставится не там, где курсор мыши, а дальше.
Не могу понять, как это исправить. Так же прилагаю изображение 512х512. Масштаб меняется по колёсику мыши.

**UI_test.py**

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from random import randint

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.resize(1300, 700)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)

        item1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('icons/settings.png'),'CamSettings', self.listWidget)
        item2 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('icons/explore.png'),'Explore', self.listWidget)

        item1.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))
        item2.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))

        item1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        item2.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 1')
        label2= QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 2')
        label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label1.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
            randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
        label2.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
            randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))

        self.img_rgb = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view_rgb = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        self.view_rgb.setScene(self.img_rgb )
        pixmap_rgb = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self.img_rgb.addPixmap('pic.png')
        border_style_rgb = f'border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;  background-color:#757575;'
        self.view_rgb.setStyleSheet(border_style_rgb)
        self.view_rgb.setFixedSize(520,520)
        self.view_rgb.mousePressEvent = Form.press_event
        #self.view_rgb.mouseMoveEvent = Form.move_event
        #self.view_rgb.mouseReleaseEvent = Form.release_event
        self.view_rgb.wheelEvent = Form.wheel_event

        first_panel_left = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        first_panel_left.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        first_panel_frame_left = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        first_panel_frame_left.setMinimumWidth(200)
        first_panel_frame_left.setLayout(first_panel_left)
        first_panel_right = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        first_panel_right.addWidget(self.view_rgb)
        first_panel_right.addStretch()
        first_panel_frame_right = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        first_panel_frame_right.setLayout(first_panel_right)
        main_first_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        main_first_box.addWidget(first_panel_frame_left)
        main_first_box.addWidget(first_panel_frame_right)
        first_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        first_container.setLayout(main_first_box)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(first_container)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label2)
        Form.setLayout(self.layout)
```

**app.py**

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from UI_test import Ui_Form
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from tools import DotPainter

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self._zoom = 0

    def press_event(self, event):
        self.clickPos = event.pos()
        self.clickBtn= event.button()
        print(self.clickPos)
        if self.clickBtn & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pointItem=DotPainter(self.ui.img_rgb,self.clickPos)

    def fitInView(self):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(0.0, 0.0, 512.0, 512.0)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.ui.view_rgb.setSceneRect(rect)
            unity = self.ui.view_rgb.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.ui.view_rgb.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.ui.view_rgb.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.ui.view_rgb.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                        viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.ui.view_rgb.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def wheel_event(self,event):
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            factor = 1.25
            self._zoom += 1
        else:
            factor = 0.8
            self._zoom -= 1
        if self._zoom > 0:
            self.ui.view_rgb.scale(factor, factor)
        elif self._zoom == 0:
            self.fitInView()
        else:
            self._zoom = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**tools.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt,QRectF,QPointF,QSizeF
from PySide2.QtGui import QPen,QColor,QBrush,QPolygonF
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class DotPainter(object):
    #класс для рисования точки
    def __init__(self, canvas, start):
        self.start = start
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.point=QRectF()
        self.width = self.point.width()
        self.height = self.point.height()
        self.PointF = QPointF(float(start.x()), float(start.y()))
        self.point.setTopLeft(self.PointF)
        self.point.setSize(QSizeF(8, 8))
        self.linePen = QPen(QtGui.QColor(255,0,0), 2)
        self.areaBrush = QBrush(QColor(255,0,0))
        self.pointItem=self.canvas.addRect(self.point,
                                              self.linePen,self.areaBrush)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #функция события мыши для получения размеров точки
        self.width = self.point.width()
        self.height = self.point.height()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могу дать полноценный ответ, так как не владею предметом. Но нашел [ссылку](https://question-it.com/questions/78843/pyqt5-koordinaty-izobrazhenija) на похожий вопрос. Там в ответе функция `getClickedPosition(self, pos) ` - которая по моему мнению должна решить вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно либо преобразовывать позицию клика в позицию сцены

```py
    def press_event(self, event):
        self.clickPos = event.pos()
        self.clickBtn = event.button()
        scenePos = self.ui.view_rgb.mapToScene(self.clickPos)
        if self.clickBtn & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pointItem = DotPainter(self.ui.img_rgb, scenePos)
```

либо привязывать обработчик кликов к самой сцене (а не вьюхе) и извлекать позицию методом `scenePos` (данный обработчик получает событие типа [QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html))

```py
  self.img_rgb.mousePressEvent = Form.scene_press_event
```

```py
    def scene_press_event(self, event):
        self.clickBtn = event.button()
        if self.clickBtn & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            DotPainter(self.ui.img_rgb, event.scenePos())
```

Comment: Ваш совет помог! Благодарю!